# Oracle CONNECT_BY query.

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-query

```
SELECT LPAD('*', 2*level-1)||SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(unit_data, '/') "battle_unit_id"
   FROM battle_units
   START WITH battle_unit_id= 600
   CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = battle_unit_id;
```

returns

```
/Doctrine
  /Doctrine/Air
    /Doctrine/Air/Jet powered aircraft
       /Doctrine/Air/Jet powered aircraft/F-16
```

All i want is just `/Doctrine/Air/Jet powered aircraft/F-16` without the other three results. Is there a way for that?

Edit:

**My oracle version:**

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.3.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

Comment: what version of oracle is this?

Comment: 11g more details given above

Comment: [Try this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9c20/7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want the leafs of the tree:

```
SELECT LPAD('*', 2*level-1)||SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(unit_data, '/') "battle_unit_id"
FROM battle_units 
WHERE connect_by_isleaf = 1  -- <<< this selects only the leaf nodes
START WITH battle_unit_id= 600
CONNECT BY PRIOR battle_unit_id = parent_id;
```

See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns001.htm#SQLRF00251

Comment: if i were to replace `CONNECT BY PRIOR gdi_schema_id = parent_id` with   `CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = gdi_schema_id;`  the new replacement gives output `F-16/Jet powered aircraft/Air/Doctrine`...which is almost what i want

Comment: related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111378/reversing-order-of-results-in-start-with-lpad-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact level where that line is going to occur this is doable.

Please see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9c20/7).

Edit: 
Since you are going for the max, [this may work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9c20/10) for you.

Comment: let's say i want the max level, but i don't know how many levels there are. how do i do it?