# Reversing order of results in START WITH LPAD SQL query

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, dml

```
SELECT LPAD('*', 2*level-1)||SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(unit_data, '/') "battle_unit_id"
   FROM battle_units
   where connect_by_isleaf = 1
   START WITH battle_unit_id= 600
   CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = battle_unit_id;
```

returns

```
*/F-16/Jet powered aircraft/Air/Doctrine
```

where,
F-16 is the great-grandchild of Doctrine.

**Question 1**
I would like to reverse this order such that i get the following:

```
*/Doctrine/Air/Jet powered aircraft/F-16
```

**Question 2**
Currently, the battle_units table have battle_unit_id from 1 to 50,000 but the above query only gives me the hierarchy of ONE battle_unit_id. Is there way to get all hierarchies of 50,000 battle_unit_ids:

ie
*/Doctrine/Air/Jet powered aircraft/F-16            (id=30)
*/Doctrine/Air/Jet powered aircraft/F-22            (id=31)
*/Doctrine/Interstellar/Non-human/Galactic-Virus    (id=45,321)
....etc

**My oracle version:**

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE 11.2.0.3.0 Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
   SELECT LPAD('*', 2*level-1)||SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(unit_data, '/') "battle_unit_id"
   FROM battle_units
   START WITH parent_id IS NULL
   CONNECT BY PRIOR battle_unit_id = parent_id;
```

This should start with all battle-units that have no parents and get all children.